# Context Menu for Directly Loading Chrome's Console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Quick question.

I develop a lot of javascript and usually end up accessing the console via right-click, inspect element, and then navigating to the console tab.

I know there are keyboard shortcuts, but I've never really been able to get used to using them.

So, what I'd like to do is create an extension for Chrome that registers another context menu item that would directly open the JS console.  I can register the context menu just fine, but don't know how to get it to actually open the console on click.  It may not be possible, but I just wanted to throw it out here to see if anyone has a solution.

Here's what I currently have:

```
chrome.contextMenus.create(
    {
        "title": "Show Console", 
        "contexts":["page","selection","link","editable","image","video","audio"],
    "onclick": function() {
            alert("working");
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that, there have been talks to do a Inspector API for Chrome. In the meantime you can use the following keyboard shortcut to open inspector:

JavaScript Console: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>

Inspector Console: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>

Comment: That's kinda what I figured.  Thanks for the info about an API for the inspector.  That'd be really cool!

Comment: Could you simulate pressing the shortcuts with javascript?

Comment: @Haliwood, no you cannot, the keyboard shortcuts are specific to Google Chrome. Allowing such thing is a security risk too :)